# Getting an error with Ballerina persistance

Tags: mysql, ballerina, persist

I'm getting below error when tried to run my code

```
Running executable

error: Error in SQL connector configuration: Failed to initialize pool: Public Key Retrieval is not allowed Caused by :Public Key Retrieval is not allowed Caused by :Public Key Retrieval is not allowed
```

I have set up mysql docker image by

```
docker pull mysql
docker run -e "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw" --name persist-mysql -p 3305:3306 -d mysql
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error seems to show up when you try to initialize the persistence client when the relevant database and tables are not created.

Creating these by manually executing the generated `script.sql` script ought to fix the issue.